# NSDateFormatter gives different output/wrong (GMT?) time

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter, gmt

I have tried setting the timezone and locale of the NSDateFormatter but I can't seem to get anything to work. Here is the code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *myFireDateString=[@"9/17/11" stringByAppendingString:@" 09:00:00"];
NSDate *myFireDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:myFireDateString];  
NSLog(@"The datestring is is %@",myFireDateString);
NSLog(@"The formatted date is %@",myFireDate);
```

Here is the output:

The datestring is is 9/17/11 09:00:00

The formatted date is 2011-09-17 13:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timezone to your dateFormatter:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

See [NSDate from NSString , shows the previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711499/nsdate-from-nsstring-shows-the-previous-day)